# Cannot implement Wikipedia sample for handling database events in FreePascal/Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal, database-events

For two weeks now I'm trying to implement a Firebird events handler to my 'daemon-like' program in FreePascal which has to work on Linux.
I think I have tried everything, but I still cannot register any event sent by a database (which should be registered in a log)- daemon isn't crashing, it keeps loggings it's activity. Two GUIs I've created (Lazarus on Windows and Ubuntu) are working without any problem.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to make daemon program with event listener? Maybe those questions aren't the smartest but I'm absolutely out of ideas.

```
Program Daemon;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$DEFINE UseCThreads}
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  SysUtils, BaseUnix, sqldb, IBConnection, FBEventMonitor;

{ TMyEventAlert }                        {c}
type
  TMyEventAlert=class
class procedure OnFBEvent(Sender: TObject; EventName: string; EventCount: longint;
 var CancelAlerts: boolean);
end;

Var
   { vars for daemonizing }
   bHup,
   bTerm : boolean;
   textPolaczenia, textZdarzenia, config : text;
   SlogPolaczenia, SlogZdarzenia,  nazwaHosta, sciezkaBazaDanych, uzytkownik, haslo: string;

   aOld,
   aTerm,
   aHup : pSigActionRec;
   ps1  : psigset;
   sSet : cardinal;
   pid  : pid_t;
   secs : longint;

   zerosigs : sigset_t;
   EventAlert : TMyEventAlert;
   EventsM :TFBEventMonitor;
   //EventAlert: TMyEventAlert;
   BConnection : TIBConnection;
   SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
   SQLTransaction1: TSQLTransaction;


   { handle SIGHUP & SIGTERM }
   procedure DoSig(sig : longint);cdecl;
   begin
      case sig of
         SIGHUP : bHup := true;
         SIGTERM : bTerm := true;
      end;
   end;



class procedure TMyEventAlert.OnFBEvent(Sender: TObject; EventName: string;
   EventCount: longint; var CancelAlerts: boolean);
   begin
     //some basic do's
     SlogZdarzenia := 'SlogZdarzenia.log';
     AssignFile(textZdarzenia,SlogZdarzenia);
     Rewrite(textZdarzenia);
     Writeln(textZdarzenia,'Cos sie zdarzylo');
     CloseFile(textZdarzenia);
     end;


Procedure WpisPolaczenie;
Begin
   AssignFile(textPolaczenia,SLogPolaczenia);
   Append(textPolaczenia);
   Writeln(textPolaczenia,'Connected to database at ',formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss',now));
   CloseFile(textPolaczenia);
End;

procedure CreateConnection;

   begin
      BConnection := TIBConnection.Create(nil);


      BConnection.DataBaseName := '/home/pi/bazydanych/aaa';
      BConnection.Hostname := 'localhost';
      BConnection.UserName:='sysdba';
      BConnection.Password:='masterkey';


      EventsM:=TFBEventMonitor.create(nil);
      EventsM.Connection:=BConnection;
      EventsM.Events.Add('baba');
      EventsM.OnEventAlert:=@EventAlert.OnFBEvent;
      EventsM.RegisterEvents;



Begin

   SlogPolaczenia := 'SlogPolaczenia.log';                        {setting up 'connection variables'}
   SlogZdarzenia:= 'SlogZdarzenia.log';
   secs := 15;


   fpsigemptyset(zerosigs);

   { set global daemon booleans }
      bHup := true; { to open log file }
      bTerm := false;

      { block all signals except -HUP & -TERM }
      sSet := $ffffbffe;
      ps1 := @sSet;
      fpsigprocmask(sig_block,ps1,nil);

      { setup the signal handlers }
      new(aOld);
      new(aHup);
      new(aTerm);
      aTerm^.sa_handler{.sh} := SigactionHandler(@DoSig);

      aTerm^.sa_mask := zerosigs;
      aTerm^.sa_flags := 0;
      {$ifndef BSD}                {Linux'ism}
       aTerm^.sa_restorer := nil;
      {$endif}
      aHup^.sa_handler := SigactionHandler(@DoSig);
      aHup^.sa_mask := zerosigs;
      aHup^.sa_flags := 0;
      {$ifndef BSD}                {Linux'ism}
       aHup^.sa_restorer := nil;
      {$endif}
      fpSigAction(SIGTERM,aTerm,aOld);
      fpSigAction(SIGHUP,aHup,aOld);

      { daemonize }
      pid := fpFork;
      Case pid of
         0 : Begin { we are in the child }
            Close(input);  { close standard in }
            Close(output); { close standard out }
            Assign(output,'/dev/null');
            ReWrite(output);
            Close(stderr); { close standard error }
            Assign(stderr,'/dev/null');
            ReWrite(stderr);
         End;
         -1 : secs := 0;     { forking error, so run as non-daemon }
         Else Halt;          { successful fork, so parent dies }
      End;

      { begin processing loop }
      Repeat
         If bHup Then Begin
            {$I-}
            Close(textPolaczenia);
            {$I+}
            IOResult;
         {$I+}
          //UtworzLogi;
         {fggggggd}

         bHup := false;
      End;
      {----------------------}
                                               {'program' part of a daemon}
      CreateConnection;



      {----------------------}
      If bTerm Then
         BREAK
      Else
         { wait a while }
         fpSelect(0,nil,nil,nil,secs*1000);
   Until bTerm;
   End.
```

Thank you Abelisto & Nested Type for your previous answers and help.

'Body' of a program is based on a free sample by CncWare, to check if is it working properly I use

tail -f SlogPolaczenie.log   // activity log

tail -f SlogEvents.log       // events log

ps ax | grep nameofaprogram

kill -TERM processIDListedafterPsAXGrepNameoOfAprogram

Comment: BTW the good point to start is try the example shipped with FPC: `packages\fcl-db\examples\fbeventstest.pp`

Comment: @Abelisto , 
thank you for your help and your time; I have spent few hours more on example you gave me, but it appears that still is something wrong with my code. An updated 'version' is listed on top.

Comment: While I download and install FB :) please make some clarifying: 1) version of FPC 2) version of FB 3) Post compilable code. In my case your code snippet finished by `Main end. }` line which is not the end of the program :)

Comment: Aye, aye! FPC version: 2.6-2.8; Firebird-Classic 2.5. I can get information from database (tested on GUI) and I'm pretty sure that it is connecting with it now.
Code above updated.

Comment: Terminal-based example `packages\fcl-db\examples\fbeventstest.pp` works fine for me. Quick GUI based example works fine too: [http://pastebin.com/T4YbPE0X](http://pastebin.com/T4YbPE0X) If you trying to create daemon then move this code\components from `TForm` to `TDataModule`.

Comment: Thank you Abelisto! It appears that only way of handling that problem was adding declaration
{$mode delphi}{$H+} after the program name. Still don't know why it has enough 'magic' to fix error, but maybe it will be helpful to someone.
Thank you for your help once again!

Comment: Nice to see that you solve the problem. However it is interesting which code is so specific for Delphi you are using :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `OnFBEvent` declaration is wrong. It has to be a method, not a global procedure:

```
procedure TSomething.OnFBEvent(Sender: TObject; EventName: string;EventCount: longint; var CancelAlerts: boolean); register;
begin
end;
```

So you have to declare somewhere such a class and create an instance:

```
type TSomething = class
  procedure OnFBEvent(Sender: TObject; EventName: string;EventCount: longint; var CancelAlerts: boolean); register;
end;
```

If you look at the sample, `OnFBEvent` is a method of `TForm1`. So if you reproduce the example in a GUI program you can also declare the method in the main form. If you're in a console then it's like explained before.

Also note that if you're not in `{$MODE DELPHI}` the event must be assigned with an `@`,

```
EventsM.OnEventAlert:= @Someting.OnFBEvent;
```

Comment: thank you, but I still can't figure it out. I have updated code listed before. Any ideas what's wrong with it?

Comment: I can't help more. My answer was related to the grammar error with event assignement. However i recommend you to try the Lazarus forum because you have facilities to attach a full project and you'll target a wider audience. S.O is more made for very specific Q. Actually the prblem you encounter is not well defined in the Q. Initially it was a lang. issue, now you've updated the Q and it's another problem...It's not right to use S.O like that. Be more specific.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right with it, adding declaration {$mode delphi}{$H+} after program name (probably) solved the problem. Thank you for helping with the function declaration issue!